# Mathematical formulas in a table

Tags: tables

I would like to draw such a table in latex with some mathematical formula. Could you please help me to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you

- Use an `array` rather than a `tabular` environment as the main structure: Since all of the table's material (other than the header row) should be typeset in math mode, using a `tabular` wouldn't be convenient as you'd have to enter lots and lots of `$` symbols (one pair for each cell) to enter and exit math mode. Note that an `array` environment must be in math mode.
- Load the `amsmath` package (you may be already doing so) and use that package's `\text` macro to render the material in the header row in an upright font shape.
- Use the `\vdots` macro to create the symbols with the three vertical dots
- Use the macros of the `booktabs` package to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines.

Here's a starter template for the table; I'll leave it to you to fill in the missing cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{array}{ ccccc }
\toprule
\text{harmonic} & \text{period} & \text{frequency} & \text{frequency} & \text{contribution}\\
& & (\text{cycle/samp.~int.}) & (\text{rad/samp.~int.}) & \text{to variance}\\
\midrule
1 & n & 1/n & 2\pi/n & \frac{1}{2}A_1^2\\
2 & & & & \\
3 & & & & \\
\vdots & & & & \\
n/2-1 & & & & \\
n/2 & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```